# SQl queries searching by date range

Tags: sql, ms-access, datetime, ms-access-2007

I have a table in an Access 2007 database. All fields are of type text. Can the following be done using the where clause? If so how?

- SELECT * from Table1 WHERE (ColumnDate is between 26th and 19th of march 2010)
- SELECT * from Table1 WHERE (ColumnAge is between 25 and 40)

The usual < <= operators don't seem to work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * from Table1 WHERE (CDATE(ColumnDate) BETWEEN #03/26/2010# AND #03/19/2010#)
SELECT * from Table1 WHERE (CINT(ColumnAge) between 25 and 40)
```

Dates are represented in Access between `#` symbols in **`#MM/DD/YYYY#`**.
You should really be storing the date as a date field :)

Comment: Thanks,

I need to search for those who are aged between 25 and 40 both included.

Comment: `BETWEEN` results include both outer range values. You should be getting those people aged between 25 and 40.

Comment: Thanks Once again, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * from Table1 WHERE ColumnDate between '2010-03-26' and '2010-03-19'
SELECT * from Table1 WHERE ColumnAge between 25 and 40
```

I don't use Access, so YMMV.

Comment: You don't use Access and you posted SQL that won't run in Access. The first one will work if the column has all the dates stored as yyyy-mm-dd, but not otherwise. The second won't work because the original question said that all the fields are text.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting `ColumnDate` to actual date/time with `CDate` function. Conversion to int can be done with `CInt`, I guess.

I don't use Access, so it's just a common-sense guess.

Comment: Are these inbuilt SQL functions, If so how are they called in a query. An example would be appreciated.

Comment: Actually Anton Gogolev's answer reminded me to put them into my sample. So, he deserves an upvote from me :)

Answer (score 0):

Mr.David-W-Fenton is right saying that the first one `SELECT * from Table1 WHERE ColumnDate between '2010-03-26' and '2010-03-19'` by Marcelo doesn't work, and wrong suggesting the cause. The clause is incorrect because of quotes around string representations of dates, the date format is pretty OK. So I'd assume

`SELECT * from Table1 WHERE CDATE(ColumnDate) between #2010-03-26# and #2010-03-19#`

as a proper solution.

Comment: Phew, you're right, I just followed Marcelo. Thank you, fixing the query.